# Simulation of JUnit output for the given input

Tags: junit, system-rules

```
public void MyTest {
 @Rule
   public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock
  = emptyStandardInputStream();

 @Test
 public void shouldTakeUserInput() {
    systemInMock.provideLines("add 5", "another line");
     InputOutput inputOutput = new InputOutput();
    assertEquals("add 5", inputOutput.getInput());
 }
}
```

Here, I want to check for the input add 5 my output should some statement using `System.out.println()` statement within some method. Is It possible to simulate output statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SystemOutRule`](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/apidocs/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/SystemOutRule.html) to get the output written to `System.out` and assert against it:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = 
        emptyStandardInputStream();

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Test
    public void shouldTakeUserInput() {
        systemInMock.provideLines("add 5", "another line");

        MyCode myCode = new MyCode();
        myCode.doSomething();

        assertEquals("expected output", systemOutRule.getLog());
    }
}
```

Comment: myCode.doSomething() is using println(), when try to get through getLog test case is not passed, If I use print method it's getting pass

Comment: @SasirekaGanesan `println` adds a newline to the output. If you use it, you should assert against `"expected output\n"`.